# does writing to xlsx works with existing macros in the file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an xlxs file ( calculations file) with a number of sheets where the values for a few parameters are calculated using macros. These calculations are based of a particular column values in SHEET1 and this column values are copied from a set of different files ( Input files) repetitively and after a shortwhile the parameter values are copied over to another file. I am trying to automate this process with pandas. I was able copy column data from input files to the calculations file but the macros doesn't seem to be doing anything as I can not see any changed values even after waiting for a minute. Usually these macros take only a few seconds. On the other hand if I print the column from the calculations dataframe, it shows the copied values from input. not sure what's missed here.

here is the code I am using for the process

```
input_file = os.path.join('./data',configs.input_file)
calculations_file = os.path.join('./resources', configs.calculations_file)

input_df = pd.read_csv(normal_file)    
calcs_df = pd.read_excel(calculations_file)

# first column is what is used in calculating the parameter values.
# so copy input data to this column
calcs_df[calcs_df.columns[0]] = input_df[input_df.columns[0]]

# wait for sometime so that the macros can run and derive the parameter values
time.sleep(90)

# check the columns for parameters for their updated values, 10, 11, 12 are
# the columns for the parameters.

print(calcs_df[calcs_df.columns[0]][1],calcs_df[calcs_df.columns[10]][0],calcs_df[calcs_df.columns[11]][0],calcs_df[calcs_df.columns[12]][0] )
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me understand this sort of process is even possible.

Comment: Are you trying to write data into your calculation file?

Comment: Hi @user14518362 yes I am writing to the calculations file. I managed to solve the problem using xlwings.

Answer (score 0):

**xlwings** does this well for me.

instead of using pandas used xlwings as follows and it worked

```
nwbook = xw.Book(n_file)
nwsheet = nwbook.sheets[0]

rwbook = xw.Book(r_file)
isheet = rwbook.sheets['Test']

ndata = nwsheet.range('A:A').options(ndim=2,expand='table', 
transpose=True).value

 
# calculations file edits
cwbook = xw.Book(c_file)
csheet = cwbook.sheets['Data']

for no, data in enumerate(ndata):
    # this is where the calculations are done 
    # get result in column orientation by setting
    # transpose to true.
    csheet.range('A:A').options(ndim=2, 
    expand='table',transpose=True).value = data
    time.sleep(1)

    # by now the macros in the calculations sheet are run
    # and the results ready
    # read values and pump them to report
    isheet.range('A'+str(no)).value = data[0]
    isheet.range('C'+str(no)).value = csheet.range('E2').value
    isheet.range('D'+str(no)).value = csheet.range('F2').value
    instant_sheet.range('E'+str(no)).value = csheet.range('G2').value
```